# I want to use the same button in a form to first add elements then remove elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am working on a form where I want to use a button to add functionality to that form, change the attributes of the button then use  remove those same elements.  I have gotten the part to work that adds  the elements and the functionality and changes the attributes of the button but I can't get it to remove the added elements.
Below is the test code with the form.  In the end I want to add the elements to update a database by using the same button to add the form, submit the data then remove the elements.

```
    $(function(){
            $("#addform").click(function(){
                var adddiv = $("<div>").attr('id','addediv').addClass("incident").append(
                    $("<label>").addClass("title").text("TO BE COMPLETED BY THE SUPERVISOR"),
                    $("<div>").append(
                        $("<input>").attr("type", "text").attr("id",   "incidate").addClass("datepick")

                        )
                    );
                $(".incident").remove();
                $("form").append(adddiv);
                $(function(){
                    $(".datepick").datepicker({
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true
                    });
                    }
                );
                $("#addform").attr('value','Remove Form').attr('id','removeForm');

            });
        });

        $(function(){
            $("#removeForm").click(function(){
                $("#addediv").remove();  
            })
        })

     </script>


 <form>
   <input type="button" id="addform" value="Add form" />
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're overcomplicating the process.  It would be simpler and easier to read if you had two buttons and two event handlers.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" Value="Add"/>
<input type="button" id="btnRemove" Value="Remove" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function(){
    $(this).css("display", "none");
    $("#btnRemove").css("display", "inline-block");
    //Add your stuff here
});

$("#btnRemove").click(function(){
    $(this).css("display", "none");
    $("#btnAdd").css("display", "inline-block");
    //Remove your stuff here
});
```

Your problem seems to be caused because your functions aren't using "on" or "live" which means that the binding occurs on page load.  Since "btnRemove" doesn't exist at that time, the event handler never truly binds to it.  You can, of course, add the binding after you change the value and id of your button, but that's unnecessarily complex, so I think the above solution is much better and more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply different logic here. Instead of changing id, you can use label and add a condition to hide and show the form.

I have [modified your code](http://jsfiddle.net/wpheyqz4/)

```
$(function() {

$("#addform").click(function() {

    if ($("#addform").attr('value') != "Remove Form") {

        var adddiv = $("<div>").attr('id', 'addediv').addClass("incident").append(
        $("<label>").addClass("title").text("TO BE COMPLETED BY THE SUPERVISOR"),
        $("<div>").append(
        $("<input>").attr("type", "text").attr("id", "incidate").addClass("datepick")

        ));
        $(".incident").remove();
        $("form").append(adddiv);

        $("#addform").attr('value', 'Remove Form');

    } else {
        $("#addediv").remove();
        $("#addform").attr('value', 'Add form');
    }
 });


});
```